# Creating java code to prompt user for password and allow only 3 attempts then quit the programme

Tags: java

I have been experimenting with trying to get the code below running WITHOUT using a break statement (but i can't figure it out)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Password
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        final String PASSWORD = "Test";

        for (int passAttempts = 0; passAttempts < 3; passAttempts++) 
        {
            System.out.print("\nEnter Your Password: ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String inputPass = input.nextLine();

            if (!(inputPass.equals(PASSWORD))) 
            {
                System.out.println("\nWrong Password Try Again");
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("\nWelcome!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my alternative attempt of trying to use a switch statement to "catch" each iteration of the loop and perform an action, but I'm  not sure why its endless loop:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Password2
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        final String PASSWORD = "Test";

        System.out.print("\nEnter Your Password: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputPass = input.nextLine();

        do
        {
            for(int passAttempts = 0; passAttempts < 3; passAttempts++)
            {
                switch(passAttempts)
                {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("\nWrong password try again\t2 attempts remaining");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("\nWrong password try again\t1 attempts remaining");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("\nWrong password try again\t0 attempts remaining");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("\nContact Help desk");
                        break;
                }  
            }    
        }
        while(!(inputPass.equals(PASSWORD)));
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Actually, break just jumps out of the loop. If you actually want to exit the application, why not just call System.exit ?

Comment: while(password incorrect && password tries < 3)

Comment: Why are you running without breakpoints? Breakpoints are there to be used to help you debug your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this, alternatively instead of comparing password in while statement put a break statement below the if(password.equals(PASSWORD), but since you said you want to avoid it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final String PASSWORD = "Test";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int attempts = 3;
    String password = "";
    while (attempts-- > 0 && !PASSWORD.equals(password)) //compares and then decrements
    {
        System.out.print("Enter your password: ");
        password = sc.nextLine();
        if (password.equals(PASSWORD)) 
            System.out.println("Welcome");
        else 
            System.out.println("Incorrect. Number of attempts remaining: " + attempts);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand where I was going wrong. Total logic fail on my part. The reason my code loops is because the for loop is counting up from zero. 0,1,2. Then going straight into the switch statement and printing EVERYTHING endlessly.

Comment: @eamonn-keogh The endless loop is caused by the fact that you don't have any code to change inputPass inside the loop, so once the wrong password has been entered, you are stuck in an endless loop because the condition !inputPass.equals(PASSWORD) is always fullfilled.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it for me, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, as an additional note generally if you want to receive some input several times, it has to be in a loop, your code only reads a single line once.

Comment: thats correct, in the 2nd example it will only read it once like you said. I have much to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a while and some flags:

```
final String PASSWORD = "Test";
    final int MAX_PASS_ATTEMPS = 3;
    boolean isLoggedIn = false;
    int passAttemps = 0;
    while (passAttemps < MAX_PASS_ATTEMPS && !isLoggedIn) {
        System.out.print("\nEnter Your Password: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputPass = input.nextLine();

        if (!(inputPass.equals(PASSWORD))) {
        System.out.println("\nWrong Password Try Again");
        passAttemps++;
        } else {
        System.out.println("\nWelcome!");
        isLoggedIn =true;
        break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So while passAttempts are less then 3 and not isLoggedIn equals true? Im lost the boolean part I don't fully understand

Do
    some code

Comment: You should read it like this:
While passAttemps are less than max pass attemps and the user is not logged in ask for password, else show the message Welcome and set the user logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Using flag without change your code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Password {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String PASSWORD = "Test";
        boolean wrongPass = true;

        for (int passAttempts = 0; passAttempts < 3 && wrongPass; passAttempts++) {
            System.out.print("\nEnter Your Password: ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String inputPass = input.nextLine();

            if (!(inputPass.equals(PASSWORD))) {
                System.out.println("\nWrong Password Try Again");
            } else {
                System.out.println("\nWelcome!");
                wrongPass = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ps: close your Scanner ;)

Comment: Thanks, I feel like I need to brush up on boolean logic after that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following code in the end after some experimentation. The reasoning behind the programme...does the programme quit because the initialised boolean value of false is changed to true? Or is it because of the value changing in the for loop? Its works but its a bit tricky to explain why it functions hmm...

The for loop to my understanding behaves like so;

- is 1 <= 3? Yes, so its True...and NOT false = TRUE
- is 2 <= 3? Yes, so its True...and NOT false = TRUE
- is 3 <= 3? Yes, so its True...and NOT false = TRUE
- is 4 <= 3? No, so its false...and NOT false = false -> breaks loop

The part I'm confused on is declaring the boolean value as TRUE when the right password is entered, I don't grasp why it quits the programme...

Can someone clarify this for me with an equation perhaps?
Many thanks.

```
final String PASSWORD = "Test"; //sets constant password 
final int MAX_PASS_ATTEMPTS = 3; //sets constant attempts
boolean adminLoggedIn = false;

    for(int passAttempts = 1; passAttempts <= MAX_PASS_ATTEMPTS && !adminLoggedIn; passAttempts++) //compares and increments passAttempts
    {
        System.out.print("\nPassword: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputPass = input.nextLine();

            if (!(inputPass.equals(PASSWORD))) //If "Cisco" is not entered as password
            {
                System.out.println("\nERROR! Wrong Password! \t" + ((passAttempts - MAX_PASS_ATTEMPTS)*(-1)) + " Attempts Remaining"); //Deducts amount of attempts remaining
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("\nWelcome!");
                adminLoggedIn = true; //breaks loop 
            } 
}
```